# datepicker custom styles not applying after selecting date

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, datepicker

```
beforeShowDay: function(date){ 
return [true, "my-style"];
}

$(".my-style a").attr("style", "background:"+background_button+" !important; color:"+text_button+" !important;");

<td data-year="2015" data-month="8" data-event="click" data-handler="selectDay" class="my-style ui-datepicker-current-day"><a href="#" class="ui-state-default myClass ui-state-active" style="background:#BDC42F !important; color:#C71414 !important;">21</a></td>
```

But When I click on any date, it's changing to

```
<td data-year="2015" data-month="8" data-event="click" data-handler="selectDay" class="my-style ui-datepicker-current-day"><a href="#" class="ui-state-default ui-state-active">21</a></td>
```

So, the style is not applying. May be datepicker will refresh everytime when a date is selected? Any solution please.